# How to check how much space a table is using in Informix?

Tags: informix

Is there a way in Informix to identify what percentage of an underlying table space (dbspace) a table is consuming?

Comment: Yes, but it's moderately complex, especially if the table is fragmented.  You'll want to look at the SysMaster database and/or ON-Check and/or ON-Stat.  I'm working on  the assumption that you are seeking to find the amount of space used by a given table in a specified dbspace as a percentage of the total space available in the dbspace.  You might do better searching the mailing list archives at the [IIUG](http://www.iiug.org/) — the International Informix User Group.  You might have to join (free, not much incoming email) to get access to them.